# Getting SSL certificate for AWS EB

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I deployed a DRF application on Elastic Beanstalk and now I need to make it https.
I requested a public certificate from AWS ACM using EB URL for domain name but got the following message.

```
You cannot request a certificate for Amazon-owned domain names such as those ending in amazonaws.com, cloudfront.net, or elasticbeanstalk.com.
```

Now the question is can I get a certificate without spending money on domain?

I tried to get a free subdomains but none of them had the functionality to manage DNS settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> can I get a certificate without spending money on domain?

No. For valid SSL certificate you need your own domain, or domain that you control. There are free domain providers, but for anything other than testing, you need to pay for a domain.